# Laravel 5 inserting image when register

Tags: php, laravel

As I understand this code:

```
   return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'image'    => $data->file('image')
                        ->move(
                           public_path('images'), 
                           $request->file('image')
                                   ->getClientOriginalName())
```

creates a user. The problem is when I select the image file in registration form I can't upload it to the database's profile table. I don't know how to pass that last line of the code to make it work:

```
 'image' => $data->file('image')
                    ->move(
                       public_path('images'), 
                       $request->file('image')
                               ->getClientOriginalName())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the file on the server and the file path in the database your code could look like this.

```
 $user = new User();
 $user->name = Input::get('name');
 $user->email = Input::get('email');
 $user->password = hash(Input::get('password'));
 if(Input::hasFile('image')){
    $file = Input::file('image');
    $file = $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$file->getOriginalFileName());
    $user->image = $file->getRealPath();
 }
 $user->save();
 return $user;
```

If you want to store the image in the database you would have to adjust this slightly.

Comment: I'm getting this error "file() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given" on this line ->>> file()->getOriginalFileName());

Comment: @feknaz Sorry I think there was a type, I believe it should be `$file->getOriginalFileName()`

Comment: Finally, I made some adjustments and everything is now working! Thank you!