# How can I store saved filename in database : laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to store filename that is actually stored in the folder in my database. I'm saving files as their original names. Everything works properly except that when I try to store the names in database, some temporary file names are stored instead of intended names. Where did I go wrong?

```
$student = new Student();
    $student->create($request->all());
    $gradeId = $request->grade_id;
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->storeAs('public', $filename);
    $student->image = $filename;
    return redirect()->route('index', compact('gradeId'));
```

'C:\xampp\tmp\phpA812.tmp' this is stored in the database but when I echo out $filename it gives correct name.

Comment: I see request handling code, but I'm not seeing database handling code in your question.

Comment: How do you mean? I've created an instance of Student model and tried to insert $filename in $student->image column. Is that not enough?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31259240/4874281

Comment: You are creating first then assigning the filename to the image, may be you need to assign the student properties first then save

Comment: @linktohref thanks for the reminder.. that worked.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the student properties individually rather than mass assigning it.

```
$student = new Student(); 

$student->name = $request->input('name');
// Set other properties

$file = $request->file('image');
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
$file->storeAs('public', $filename);

$student->image = $filename;

$student->save();
return redirect()->route('index', compact('gradeId'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the create method cause it will directly save the new model.
Do the following:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$student = new Student();
$student->name = $request->name;
$student->age = $request->age;
$student->image = $filename;
$student->save();
```

Just specify all fields individual and then hit the save method. Name and age are examples!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the below line

```
 $student->image = $filename;
```

with

```
  Student::where('id', $student->id)->update(['image' => $filename]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To store all attributes of a file in the database, you can use this package:

```
https://github.com/Saeid-Khaleghi/media-store
```